# data-ng-model and data-ng-change are not working with data-ng-selected

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, model-view-controller, angular-ui-bootstrap

```js
var appCompAssets = angular.module('app.company.assets', []);

appCompAssets.controller('locationDetailCTRL', function($scope, $http) {
  // LOAD LOCATION DETAILS

  $scope.loadBranches = function() {

    $http.get('../getBranches_id_name/' + $scope.compid)
      .then(
        function(response) {
          if (response.data.length !== 0) {
            $scope.getBranches_id_name = response.data;
            console.log($scope.getBranches_id_name);
          }
        },
        function(response) {
          // error handling routine
          console.log('$Error: no data for branch id & name');
        });
  };

  $scope.loadLocations = function(branch_id) {
    $scope.branchid = branch_id;
    $http.get('../getLocations_id_name/' + $scope.branchid)
      .then(

        function(response) {

          if (response.data.length !== $scope.branchid) {
            $scope.getLocations_id_name = response.data;
            console.log($scope.getLocations_id_name);
          }

        },
        function(response) {
          // error handling routine
          console.log('$Error: no data for location id & name');
        });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="app.company.assets" data-ng-controller="locationDetailCTRL">

  <div class="row" data-ng-init="loadBranches()">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="branch_id" class="small"><i>Branch</i>
        </label>
        <select class="form-control input-sm" data-ng-init="loadLocations(assetInfo.branch_id)" data-ng-change="loadLocations(assets.branch_id)" id="branch_id" name="branch_id" data-ng-model="assets.branch_id">
          <option data-ng-selected="assetInfo.branch_name ===b.branch_name" data-ng-repeat="b in getBranches_id_name" value="{{b.id}}">{{b.branch_name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="location_id" class="small"><i>Location</i>
        </label>

        <select class="form-control input-sm" id="location_id" name="location_id">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option data-ng-repeat="l in getLocations_id_name" value="{{l.id}}" data-ng-selected="l.location_name == assetInfo.location_name">{{l.location_name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Guys, I am having problem with making data-ng-selected, data-ng-model and data-ng-change work at the same time.

if without the data-ng-model and data-ng-change

the data-ng-selected is working fine.

Excluded data-ng-model and data-ng-change and remain only data-ng-selected, the output is as below:

[image]

Although, it is able to display the value wanted, when changing the branch(dropdown), the location(s) for the respective branch won't change since there are no ng-change and ng-model exist.

However, if with all the above mentioned data-ng attribute together(data-ng-model,ng-change and ng-selected), it will not display properly as the branch is not selected which it supposed to be selected. The output is as below:

[image]

for changing the branch and the location will change, that part is working fine.

Your kind assistance will be appreciated. Thank you!.

The response result on the top is for branch and the one at the bottom is for location. Thank you.

[image: Response result]

Comment: could you provide the response data of both the $http.get call?

Comment: Hi @Deep, i have provided you with the response data of both $http.get call. Thank you.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/DgxzJSMXE54keJeM6Kac?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a cascading dropdown list, well your html code seems complex to me for what you're trying to achieve.

You can simplify it as follows.

```js
angular
 .module("demo", [])
 .controller("DefaultController", DefaultController);
  
  function DefaultController() {
   var vm = this;
    vm.branches = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Testing Branch 1' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Testing Branch 2' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Testing Branch 3' }
    ];
    
    vm.locations = [
      { id: 1, branchId: 1, name: 'Office Room 1' },
      { id: 2, branchId: 1, name: 'Office Room 2' },
      { id: 3, branchId: 2, name: 'Office Room 3' },
      { id: 4, branchId: 3, name: 'Office Room 4' }
    ];
    
    vm.loadLocations = loadLocations;
    
    // set data
    getData();
    
    function loadLocations(branchId) {
      // load locations here when branch is changed.
      // if locations are loaded only when a branch is selected
      // then you can remove the filter in ng-options for Location
      console.log('Selected BranchId: ' + branchId);
    };
    
    function getData() {
      // get data via AJAX here and set the selected options in the view via data binding (ngModel)
      var data = {
       branch: {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Testing Branch 3'
        },
        location: {
          id: 4,
          branchId: 3,
          name: 'Office Room 4'
        }
      };
      
      vm.branch = data.branch.id;
      vm.location = data.location.id;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <h1>Cascading DropDownList</h1>
    <hr />
    <h4>Branch</h4>
    <select ng-options="branch.id as branch.name for branch in ctrl.branches"
            ng-model="ctrl.branch"
            ng-change="ctrl.loadLocations(ctrl.branch)">
      <option value="">Select Branch</option>
    </select>
    <h4>Location</h4>
    <select ng-options="location.id as location.name for location in ctrl.locations | filter: { branchId: ctrl.branch }"
            ng-model="ctrl.location"
            ng-disabled="!ctrl.branch">
      <option value="">Select Location</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, however it still not solving my problem. May i know how to initially make the branch and the respective location selected when loading the page. For example, i want "Testing Branch 2" and the location : "Office Room 2" to be selected when the page is loaded. Please noted that the value for branch and location to be selected is not fix, e.g. it might be "Testing Branch 3" and "Office Room 4" that need to be selected. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @abdul mateen mohammed, do you might look at the new/last question i posted above as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try like this, hope it helps , let me know in case you are looking for something different.

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/VE5ja2kkV9Xp7og1CkAl?p=preview

in script

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.branches = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Testing Branch 1'},
  { id: 2, name: 'Testing Branch 2'},
  { id: 3, name: 'Testing Branch 3'}
];

$scope.locations = [
  { id: 1, branchId: 1, name: 'Office Room 1'},
  { id: 2, branchId: 1, name: 'Office Room 2'},
  { id: 3, branchId: 2, name: 'Office Room 3'},
  { id: 4, branchId: 3, name: 'Office Room 4'}
];

$scope.loadLocations = function(branchId) {
  console.log('Selected BranchId: ' + branchId);
};

// for selecting options on page load set the model for both the select

$scope.selectedBranchId =  2;
$scope.selectedLocationId =  3;
```

});

in view.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<h1>Cascading DropDownList</h1>
<hr />
<h4>Branch</h4>
<select ng-options="branch.id as branch.name for branch in branches"
        ng-model="selectedBranchId"
        ng-change="loadLocations(selectedBranchId)">
  <option value="">Select Branch</option>
</select>
<h4>Location</h4>
<select ng-options="location.id as location.name for location in locations | filter: { branchId: selectedBranchId }"
        ng-model="selectedLocationId"
        ng-disabled="!selectedBranchId">
  <option value="">Select Location</option>
</select>

</body>
```

Comment: Hi @Deep, do you might look at the new/last question i posted above as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
                 <div class="row" data-ng-init="loadBranches()">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for ="branch_id" class="small"><i>Branch</i></label>
                            <select class = "form-control input-sm" 
                                    data-ng-options="b.id as b.branch_name for b in getBranches_id_name" data-ng-init="branch_id = assetInfo.branch_id" data-ng-model="branch_id"
                                    data-ng-change="loadLocations(branch_id)" id="branch_id" 
                                    name="branch_id"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                          
                <div class="row" data-ng-init="loadLocations(branch_id)">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for ="location_id" class="small"><i>Location</i></label>
                            <select class = "form-control input-sm"
                                    data-ng-options="l.id as l.location_name for l in getLocations_id_name" 
                                    id="location_id" name="location_id" data-ng-init="location_id = assetInfo.location_id" data-ng-model="location_id" data-ng-disabled="!branch_id" ></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Hi @Deep and @abdul mateen mohammed, with the above code, it works as i wanted, however, there is a problem, i could not save the value to the database (the value of the selected option is not saved to the database).

But with the code below, i can save the value to the database but it won't work as i wanted which by default it will pre-load the branch and location when on load. The only changes i made is by adding the "track by" in the ng-option.

```
                 <div class="row" data-ng-init="loadBranches()">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for ="branch_id" class="small"><i>Branch</i></label>
                            <select class = "form-control input-sm" 
                                    data-ng-options="b.id as b.branch_name for b in getBranches_id_name track by b.id" data-ng-init="branch_id = assetInfo.branch_id" data-ng-model="branch_id"
                                    data-ng-change="loadLocations(branch_id)" id="branch_id" 
                                    name="branch_id"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                          
                <div class="row" data-ng-init="loadLocations(branch_id)">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for ="location_id" class="small"><i>Location</i></label>
                            <select class = "form-control input-sm"
                                    data-ng-options="l.id as l.location_name for l in getLocations_id_name track by l.id" 
                                    id="location_id" name="location_id" data-ng-init="location_id = assetInfo.location_id" data-ng-model="location_id" data-ng-disabled="!branch_id" ></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Your kind assistance will be appreciated. Thank you.

@Deep, this is how i saved the data to database. Thank you.
IN THE CONTROLLER:

```
function update() {
    $this->model->update($_POST);
}
```

IN THE MODEL:

```
function update($data) {


    $assetid = $data['assetid'];
    unset($data['assetid']); // remove @assetid element from the array @data


    $this->db->update('assets', $data, "`id` = {$assetid}");
```

}

Comment: Why can't you save the value to the database, could you explain. Do you want a complete branch model in order to save to the database

Comment: @kelvin : Could you update the plunker i provide you and recreate your issue.?

Comment: @abdul mateen mohammed: by including the track by in ng-option, i can save the value to the database. however, the value that supposed to be selected will not be selected when on load. e.g. "Testing Branch 1" and "Office Room 1" will not be selected which it supposed to be selected when on load. I'm new to augularjs so i'm sorry for any inconvenienced caused.

Comment: You can use the track by clause when you want to set the selected option by using a property which is different from the one specified in the as clause ( meaning that it is different from the property which you retrieve when the user selects a value from the <select> element ). Typically it could be done when you want to get the whole object when user selects a value but you will only set the id when the page loads, so you track by the id property in order to set the selected option check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751344/dropdown-is-not-populating-with-json-object/

Comment: @kelvin I wanted to see your code on how are you saving the detals

Comment: Thanks @abdul mateen mohammed, i will try to solve the problem with the solution you provided.

Comment: @Deep, i have provided you, how i save the details to database. Thank you.

Comment: @kelvin in the plunker i do not see any http post call, only 2 select box are there in html

Comment: @Deep, may i know what is http post call, can you give me an example, thanks.

Comment: Abdul mateen mohammed, Deep, I managed to fix the problem with the help from my friend. Thanks a lot to you guys for contributing ideas so me and my friend can figure out how to fix the problem.